# WordPress Multisite – site in sub-subdomain "not found"

Tags: wordpress, subdomain

In a WordPress installation (on a subdomain), I activated multisite, based in subdomains. This way, **every site on this network would fill a sub-subdomain** (yes, sub-sub).

I created a **wildcard subdomain**, referring to the same folder of the WordPress installation (this is Bluehost, btw).

The issue is that the main website (the one in a subdomain) is properly working, but **not the other sites in the network** (the ones that would be in sub-subdomains. Browser shows a "server not found" error. I can't even get to their Dashboard (although I can use the main site and network's Dashboard).

Any suggestions? Thank you very much.

Comment: Research this query at Google `multisite sub-subdomain site:wordpress.org`. Inside the results look -especially- for answers from Andrea and Ipstenu. Both their blogs are good resources too and they frequent [wordpress.se] as well.

Comment: @brasofilo, Thank you!
I ended up creating manually the sub-subdomains I needed (under cPanel).
I also found out that, besides creating the sub-subdomain, also an A DNS record is required (this happens in sub-subdomains only).